# How to change font-size code in phpStorm 8?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want change font-size bigger in IDE. How to change font-size code in phpStorm 8?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Press **Ctrl + Alt + S**, or Menu **File \ Settings...**
- Search item **Fonts**, Look at right side,  in IDE **Settings \ Colors & Fonts \ Font**:
  [image]
- In section named "**Scheme name**", press **Save As...** button, choose other name you perfered.
- In section named **Editor Font**, change default size to values what you prefered, then press **Enter**:

[image]